# Handling Empty Strings in SQL Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I am using SQL Bulk Insert to insert data into a temporary table.

My table has a column XYZ which is defined as `varchar NOT NULL` and I want if the XYZ column data in the delimited file is empty, it should be written to error file. Currently SQL BI treats it as a 0 length string and inserts into the table.

The delimited file looks like this:

```
Col1|XYZ|Col2  
abc||abc  
abc||abc  
abc|abc|abc
```

I tried using `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` in SQL BI query and created a Check constraint on XYZ column in table as XYZ <> '', but rather then writing particular row to error file, it causes the entire SQL BI to fail.

Please help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: it's SQL Server 2012 ...

Comment: can do that in 2 steps , 1 that allow null values, 2 step step- filter the null values and write them to error table ,the rest to the destination table

Comment: I need error records in an error file. Also the same file should have records that fail in step one as well. And I am trying to resist to write to text file from SQL.